# Spring Security & inMemoryAuthentication() & Bad Credentials

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a problem with simple login configuration with users set up in memory. All times I getting back Bad Credentials.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    //auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    auth.
    inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("user").password("123").roles("USER")
    .and()
    .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/location")
    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .disable();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

What I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes provided with a complete and [working sample](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/49618ce346056ca9d6f95049dc6ce0e73aaab8a4/samples/in-memory-auth/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/SecurityConfig.java?ts=4#L17-L38) and [unit tests](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/49618ce346056ca9d6f95049dc6ce0e73aaab8a4/samples/in-memory-auth/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/InMemoryAuthTests.java?ts=4#L41).

Let's simplify things a little bit. If you are using `formLogin()` all you have to do is specify a `UserDetailsBean` and you can accompany it with an encoder:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
        builder()
            .passwordEncoder(input -> passwordEncoder().encode(input))
            .username("user")
            .password("123")
            .roles("USER")
            .build(),
        builder()
            .passwordEncoder(input -> passwordEncoder().encode(input))
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
            .build()
    );
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        //application security
        .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/non-secure/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
    ;
    // @formatter:on
}
```

You are more than welcome to download the sample and run the [unit tests](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/49618ce346056ca9d6f95049dc6ce0e73aaab8a4/samples/in-memory-auth/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/InMemoryAuthTests.java?ts=4#L41) in your IDE

Now this is **not** preferred way because you have clear text passwords in your code. You can replace this with a manager that already has the [passwords encrypted](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/11ce5a0a4938ee888b6ea6e94904bf0b586fd359/samples/in-memory-auth/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/SecurityConfig.java?ts=4#L22-L36).

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
        builder()
            .username("user")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$C8c78G3SRJpy268vInPUFu.3lcNHG9SaNAPdSaIOy.1TJIio0cmTK")
            .roles("USER")
            .build(),
        builder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$XvWhl0acx2D2hvpOPd/rPuPA48nQGxOFom1NqhxNN9ST1p9lla3bG")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
            .build()
    );
}
```